# How to update text of the document file in the queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-docx

```
def corrections_fn(request, file, selected_words, corrections):
parser = GingerIt()
user = request.user
document = Document(file.file)
text = ''
for line in document.paragraphs:
    matches = parser.parse(line.text)
    for obj in matches['corrections']:
        misspelled_word = obj['text']
        if misspelled_word in selected_words:
            correction = selected_words[misspelled_word]
            line.text = line.text.replace(str(misspelled_word), str(correction))
        else:
            if corrections == 'auto':
                line.text = line.text.replace(str(obj['text']), str(obj['correct']))
document.save(file.file)
return file
```

In the file variable, i'm sending the Queryset which contains file(.docx).

```
resumes = Resume.objects.filter(user=user)
for resume in resumes:
  corrections_fn(request=request, file=resume, selected_words=selected_words, corrections="show")
```

When i try to rewrite the file. It is showing "**Unsupported Operation write**" error. I searched on internet and i'm not able to find the right document to deal with this type of issue. can any help me on how to solve the issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your code appears to not be indented properly. It is invalid Python as shown. Please correct that (possibly by placing triple backticks (```) above and below the code).

Comment: Also, you're going to need to tell us the Python type of `resume.file`. We have no way of telling from your code whether that is `str`, `bytes`, `io.BytesIO` or some sort of custom internal object.